# Paste flipped keyframe cancels the other ones

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, timeline

When I keyframe a paste flipped pose, it just cancels the other keyframes I have.
Blender version: 4.0.2.
Archive link:https://workupload.com/file/t3EQL9pecVd

[Demonstration Video](https://www.veed.io/view/56c21978-247e-4016-988c-287888ee8376?panel=sharel=)

Comment: Please don't link to videos on external sites which may not be available to people reading your question in future. That site shows "This video isn’t ready" when I try to look at it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (only the armature with the existing keys)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: I've linked the page, just read the instructions, or use another platform like workupload and share the link

Comment: done! the link is in the post. I tried the blender exchange but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, only one bone is keyframed, the keyframe you see is for *upperarm_r* (see image below), you've posed the whole body but haven't created any keyframe, so no wonder why if you *Copy* then *Paste Copy Flipped* you loose the original pose. To fix that, create a keyframe on the whole original pose, flip it, keyframe again.

[image]

Comment: bro that was it. I can't believe I let that pass. Thank you so so much. Appreciate it